# Why does the randn function return a number larger than 1?

Tags: matlab, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution

I thought `randn` returns a random number which belongs to a normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation 1. Therefore, I expect to get a number in the range (0, 1). But what I get is a number not in the range (0,1).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are thinking of a uniform distribution. A normal distribution can, in theory, have very big numbers, with very low probability.

`randn` has a mean of 0 and standard deviation of 1. The normal distribution is the bell-curve / Gaussian shape, with the highest probability at the mean and probability falling off relative to the standard deviation.

What you are looking for is `rand`, which "samples" from a uniform random distribution, which gives numbers bounded between 0 and 1 with even probability at all points.

Answer (score 5):

You're confusing the [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) with the [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29).

Answer (score 2):

Another possible source of confusion:

A [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_normal_distribution) with mean `0` and *variance* `1` is often denoted *N*(0,1). This is sometimes called the standard normal distribution and implies that samples are drawn from all real numbers, i.e., the range (−∞,+∞), with a mean `0` and variance `1`. The standard deviation is also `1` in this case, but this notation specifies the variance (many screw this up). The transformation *N*(μ,σ<sup>2</sup>) = μ + σ *N*(0,1), where μ is the mean, σ<sup>2</sup> is the variance, and σ is the standard deviation, is very useful.

Similarly, a [continuous uniform distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29) over the open interval (0,1) is often denoted *U*(0,1). This is often called a standard uniform distribution and implies that samples are drawn uniformly from just the range (0,1). Similarly, the transformation *U*(a,b) = a + (b − a) *U*(0,1), where a and b represent the edges of a scaled interval, is useful.

Note that the `0`'s and `1`'s in these two cases do not represent the same things at all other than being parameters that describe each distribution. The ranges that these two distributions are sampled from are called the [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_%28mathematics%29).